# Using full site editing, can I edit just one specific post / page to be unique?

Tags: block-editor

Let's say I have a **special news report post** and I want it to have a **unique title** *(so that on the archive page it has the original post title, but on the post page it has a different title that I can set)* and maybe a different background color.

---

**Basically, what I'm trying to do is to deviate from the default single post template only for one specific post.**

---

Is this doable somehow? Or do I have to create a unique template just for that one post? Maybe there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do and I'm just confused?

Comment: if you edited that post to be unique then it would have a unique template, I'm not sure what the difference would be? My reading of this is that you want a unique template for your post without having a unique template, can you clarify things more?

Answer (score 0):

In your single template you could include a condition to print a different title

Something like

```php
if( 123 === get_the_ID() ) { // Add your special post ID here ?> 
    <h1>My custom title</h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php }
```